# Is there a way to use a custom loading bar instead of a busy cursor in Flex 4?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, cursor, loading

I have a custom progress bar I want to show loading the data instead of the showBusyCursor in Flex 4. Is it possible to use the custom progress bar instead of the busy cursor?

Here is the piece of code that currently uses the showBusyCursor

```
<npcsservice:NpcsService id="npcsService" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>
```

Comment: Set showBusyCursor to false; and then display your loading bar until your data is loaded.  Are you having a specific problems?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure to be honest. The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure what to call or pass to the custom loading bar. Do I pass an object to the loading bar? I'm just a little confused.

Comment: How did you build your custom loading bar?  That implementation will determine what you need to send in.

Answer (score 0):

Please set showBusyCursor to false. Display your progress bar until the service is returned. Hide it in result handler and fault handler.

It depends on what you are doing with the service to update the custom progress bar correctly.
If you are uploading a file to the server, you can use [this](http://weblog.cahlan.com/files/file_uploads/FileUpload.html) example and update the progress bar accurately based on the size of the file uploaded. You can view the source of this example and change it according to your needs.